# Can I somehow copy the content of 2 different excel tables into 1 table?

Tags: excel

Basically, if I have an excel table containing a list, and another excel table containing another list, I want these 2 list combined into a new cell

***Example:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are in 2 different files:

On each table add a column before the column that you want to concatenate then insert some sort of ids that are same in both tables and finally  use vlookup from both tables and concatenation.

If the tables in the same file, then a concatenate function alone would work.

Note: in the photo I included a third cell just to make a space because this “ “ did not work in my phone.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve result in various way. Most effective way will be `TEXTJOIN()` formula if your excel version have it.

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,A2:C2)
```

You can also use

```
=A2 & " " & C2
=CONCATENATE(A2," ",C2)
=CONCAT(A2:C2)
```

If your first cells do not contain trailing comma (,) still you can put comma in delimiter of `TEXTJOIN()` formula like

```
 =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A2:C2)
```

[image]